# Date header overlapping Post title

Tags: html, css, date, templates, blogger

So I moved the date header below my post title on Blogger, and on the newest post the date keeps overlapping the header. If I use margin or padding, it affects the other date headers so I'm not quite sure what to do. The blog is [here](http://www.boyfullofbooks.blogspot.com/). Here is the only code I can think to be relevant (where h3 is post title):

```
h3 {
text-align: center !important;
}

h3 a{
color: #424242;
transition: 0.5s ease;
}

h3 a:hover {
color: #58c5d2;
}

.date-header {
text-align: center !important;
float: below;
}

.date-header span {
letter-spacing: 10px !important;
}

h2 {
text-align: center !important;
}

.date-posts {
margin-top: 40px;
}

h3 {
margin-bottom: -25px !important;
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `h3` style to:

`margin-bottom: 0;`

The date is being pulled into the title because of the negative margin.

Comment: This fixed the overlapping alright, but the date is still closer to the title than the others? Any fix?

Comment: It's because you only changed the one element in the inspector. Changing it in the stylesheet should fix it for all the headers.

Comment: @dcardoso is also right - it explains that first post's appearance difference.

Comment: The stylesheet is what I changed it in.

Comment: Which one do you want? You keep changing things on live site so the appearance changes. How far below the title do you want the date?

Comment: I'd like them all to be the same as the first post. I won't make any changes to the live site until I figure it out.

Comment: Your html is still wrong, every post is inside your first post. Use the developers tools to see what I'm referring to. You shouldn't have to change any css at all.

Comment: I see what you're referring to now, but I still have no idea where the problems lies...

Comment: Did you move the date by changing the HTML structure of the template?

Comment: I did and after removing the whole thing and re-writing, it fixed. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: That's usually what happens with templates - glad the suggestion helped.

Answer (score 0):

NUKE IT!!!!!!!

```
h3 {
  /* margin-bottom: -25px !important; */
}
```

EDIT: The original question was, how can I prevent the date and the header from overlapping. This was the quick and dirty fix found by using developer tools (highly recommend chrome for this reason).

Comment: It was only there to try and fix the other date headers, however it doesn't change the issue of the first date being too close to the title.

Comment: Please provide some useful comments in your answer as to why you think this will solve the problem. Doing so will help your readers to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your html... You're not closing one or two html div tags in your first post.

[image]

Every `.post-outer` should be at the same level.

Comment: They're all closed in the template, I checked.

Comment: Well the developers tools usually respect the closing tags, it doesn't seem right to me. Also, your css is applied to all your classes, I can't see anything that could be applying a different style to the first post.