# Blogger date/ title/ spacing

Tags: html, css, blogs, blogger

I've got an issue I can't seem to straighten out on [my blog](http://www.emmalouiselayla.com/) - it's similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656359/date-header-overlapping-post-title#new-answer?newreg=2a790565049a4632ab4fa4a5869a53af) but those fixes didn't work.

I've been trying to make the gap between the date and post title consistent - the first post is Ok with the following CSS:

```
.date-header {margin-top: 6px !important;}
```

but that isn't applied to the others as there's a gap between them.

Also, I added:

```
.blog-posts {margin-top: -60px}
```

to reduce a gap between the header and first post, which is the only fix I could find.  I don't know if that's related to the first issue?

I'd appreciate any guidance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Ehm.. improve the margin-top in the date-header class? Not sure if the h2 that contains the date is the only one.. if so, then h2.date-header.. and make sure you make it !important, since the regular one already has an !important tag attached to it.. (not sure why, but then again, I didn't create the theme...)

Comment: 1. Looks like there is an issue in the html, The posts are added inside first post. The HTML needs clean up.

2. The space between title and date from second post is caused by an empty div   <div class="post-header">
<div class="post-header-line-1"></div></div>

Comment: OK thanks @Siva - what should be in '<div class='post-header'>
            <div class='post-header-line-1'/>
          </div>'?